# mySQL Is non-clustering index + not indexed field still faster than 2 x not indexed fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

For example I have table  with 3 columns:
"id", "a", "b"

id is primary key
a - field without index
b - field without index

```
CREATE TABLE samples (id INT, a INT, b INT, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

Now I want to do a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM samples where a = '77345' and b = '234234';
```

As I understand this query will be really fast if I will have index for both "a" and "b" fields, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX ab_index ON samples (a, b) USING BTREE;
```

Question:

Will select query above will be faster if I add index for "a" field only (no other indexes):

```
CREATE INDEX a_index ON samples (a) USING BTREE;
```

If yes, how much faster will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table samples:

```
create table samples (id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, a int, b int, PRIMARY KEY(id));
```

*inserted **2,483,308** records*

Testing query

```
select * from samples where a = 3434 and b = 4389;
```

*Without indexes:*

```
**Timing (as measured by the server):**

Execution time: 0:00:0.57075288

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00008100
```

*With index on (a):*

```
CREATE INDEX a_index ON samples (a) USING BTREE;

**Timing (as measured by the server):**

Execution time: 0:00:0.00021302

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00008300
```

*With index (a, b) only:*

```
CREATE INDEX ab_index ON samples (a, b) USING BTREE;

**Timing (as measured by the server):**

Execution time: 0:00:0.00019394

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00007600
```

*With (a) and (a, b) indexes:*

```
**Timing (as measured by the server):**

Execution time: 0:00:0.00022304

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00008300
```

*Dropped indexes, without any indexes again:*

```
**Timing (as measured by the server):**

Execution time: 0:00:0.57105565

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00008300
```

*With (a) only index again:*

```
Execution time: 0:00:0.00021866

Table lock wait time: 0:00:0.00008700
```

***So yes, adding (a) only index increases speed significantly.***

What is strange , explain shows that in case of (a) and (a, b) indexes present mySQL still uses (a) index for some reason.

```
explain select * from samples where a = 45 and b = 3456;
```

+----+-------------+---------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+

| id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys    | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra       |

+----+-------------+---------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+

|  1 | SIMPLE      | samples | ref  | a_index,ab_index | a_index | 5       | const |    1 | Using where |

+----+-------------+---------+------+------------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------------+

Answer (score 0):

"How much faster" questions are really quite difficult to answer without knowing a lot about the content of your data.  If you index just your `a` column, and you have a large table, but not many distinct values of `a`, MySQL will still have to scan a large chunk of your table.

An index on just `a` or just `b` will probably, but not certainly, be faster than scanning the whole table. It's really hard to know without trying it on real data. It's certainly worth trying.

Pro tip:  Never use `SELECT *` where you can, instead, enumerate the names of the columns you need. That's because the query execution planner can sometimes take shortcuts when it knows it doesn't need all the columns.

The query you've given, rewritten to say

```
SELECT id,a,b 
  FROM samples
 where a = '77345'
   and b = '234234'
```

can be very fast indeed if you have an index on (a,b,id). That's because MySQL can satisfy the whole query from the index.  It finds a, then it finds b, in the index. Then sitting right there is the id value. This is called a compound covering index. It's worth reading about.

Comment: In our select query index (a,b,id) is not required, (a, b) could be enough. But will (a) index be faster than no indexes at all?

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my point about (a,b,id). That index is able to return the value of id directly to satisfy the query, without having to go back to the original table. So it's faster, because it takes less disk io.

Comment: But will (a) index be faster than no indexes at all?